# CRUD only for the organization the user belongs to

Tags: express, sails.js

**Background**
I'm building a application where all users belongs to a Organization. I only want the user to be able to Create/Read/Update/Delete records in the Organization they belong to.

I'm using sails, but I'm looking for Connect/Express-based, or a standalone  answer as sails-permissions node module is unmaintained.

**Question**
How can one implement a authorization that allow CRUD only for the organization the user belongs to?

Answer (score 2):

We are also not relying on sails-permissions. In our app, users can be members of multiple orgs.

We are using auth0 for all authentication activities, i.e. every request must include a jwt that is included in the request header. The jwt includes userId, orgId and role.

Sails policies decode the jwt and attach userId, orgId and role the the req object for all later checks.

Every model has the property orgId - we are using MongoDB. 
Every controller, db operation, etc. adds this verified orgId to the query. Actually we have a small pipeline preparing the query: we add the orgId, in update cases we filter out unwanted property updates, etc.

This approach does not require additional db calls for separation of tenants.

Some models have specific access requirements per individual RECORD. Here we store allowedUser properties (one for read, one for update, etc.) on exactly this record and we extend the query once more so that only records are returned or updated or Xyz where the current user is included in the applicable allowedUsers property.

This approach also does not require additional db calls. This leverages MongoDB-specific query features, though.

We currently do not have ACL-like requirements which would be right between the 2 approaches I described above (re access control granularity).

Comment: _"Every model has the property orgId - we are using MongoDB. Every controller, db operation, etc. adds this verified orgId to the query. Actually we have a small pipeline preparing the query: we add the orgId, in update cases we filter out unwanted property updates, etc."_ 

Any chance you can provide a example of how you inject this into .Find() etc?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to intercept each request using [middlewares](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router)

combine them with a role system by checking if a certain token is present on request headers and in a acl map and finally, if the token is present in the acl map, see which permissions are related with this token.